# Don't show the vote counts of review audits

Tags: feature-request, review-audits

I noticed that it's possible to *cheat* the review audit system in the First post and Late answer queue. If the reviewer has 1k reputation he can just click on the score and see the real number of up and downvotes, if it's a high quality post ornot a review audit.

[image: high quality post screenshot]
If it's a low quality post, it will only show an error:

[image: low quality post screenshot]

My suggestion is to disable showing the vote counts or always to display 0/0.

Comment: You paid attention during a review ... goal has been achieved :)

Comment: All other queues you can't see the vote split, why make this different? I agree that the split should be hidden.

Comment: You can also "cheat" in the "Low quality"-section by noticing that the post that was "flagged" has 5+ upvotes and was written by some 10k+ user.

Comment: _My suggestion is to disable showing the vote counts_ - NO!! This will mark it as an review audit so users know that they must pay attention. Let it always be 0/0

Comment: I tried this on a review audit and this seems to be fixed now.

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations, you were paying attention, the audit was successful in its goal of ensuring you were paying attention.

It is not *designed* to trick people.  It's designed to make sure that they're paying at least the slightest bit of attention.

Comment: yeah, but I only need to click on the score and will never fail, even if I don't read the post at all

Comment: @Dirty if you have the presence of mind to click there, you're already paying infinitely more attention than the people the audits are there to catch.

Comment: @Dirty-flow There are half a dozen similar mechanisms to which one can tell that a post is an audit.  Removing some of them is impossible, removing others removes valuable information for *real* audits.  For example, in this case, seeing the votes on a *real* post is important; that's not something you want to take away just to make audits harder.  When you end up inhibiting the ability of real reviews just for the sake of audits the audits end up being more harmful than helpful.