# Reviewing the 'review audits' system

Tags: discussion, bug, review-audits

I have read many complains about the `review audits` system, so it is clear that (in my opinion) the system needs refinement. The purpose of this post is to pinpoint some possible bugs and functionality that needs improvement.

What user this system targets? "Pay attention" is very broad, I can pay the minimum attention and 'cheat' to pass most of the tests.

So for every test, the system is lying to see your behavior. But it lies in a childish way and so a user can cheat. I am 'new reviewer' so I am under test more often and so I built the following case, for every post that it was appearing for review I was just noticing every thing else except from the question content. I tried to put the minimum effort and spend the minimum amount of time the way a bad reviewer is going to do. Even though I successfully identify and pass the tests. Here are some examples that made me suspicious about if I am being under a test:

- If a question or answer has been already deleted or closed, I can not comment on it. I am clicking the 'add comment' control but nothing happens.
- The stats on the right are not consistent. It says that a question is posted today but it has already over a thousand views and some answers.
- (this needs more effort) If you click on the question name you can see the real stats (votes, comments) of the questions.

Summarizing I think to build a better system, the system should be 'sealed' from the outer world, every stat or information except the question and the answer (even the title or the user names)  should be random or fake. Additionally the user should not have the option to easily (e.g by a web link) to link the 'fake' case with the real one.

**Update**

After going through the related posts, this question has answer in:

1. [Don't show the vote counts of review audits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255004/2279200)
2. ["Audit" review item showed "protected", revealed as audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251248/2279200)